# Glossaries add figure (image) after every entry

Tags: graphics, floats, glossaries

My glossary looks like this:

```
\renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries #1}
\renewcommand*{\entryname}{Hitza}
\renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Deskribapena}
\renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{Orrialdeak\\}

\newglossaryentry{glos:entry1}{name=entry1, description={blablabla.}}

...

\newglossaryentry{glos:entryN}{name=entryN, description={blablabla.}}
```

I need to add a figure (an image) after each glossary entry, so that I can show an image of the entry I just explained.

I guess I'll need to modify the newglossaryentry command, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @FelixPhl No. That's adding an image INSTEAD OF the description. I want to keep the description and add an image.

Comment: you can simply add text to the description and still use the command from the linked question, then you have both